# Problema ao carregar atributos globais (data-*) com jQuery

Tags: jquery, funções

Oi, pessoal da SO. Podem me ajudar com meu dever de casa?
Sou iniciante em jQuery e preciso resolver um "enigma" que meu professor propôs para a turma e nos permitiu pesquisar aqui no site.

Bom, temos uma lista onde são relacionados alguns modelos de carros e suas cores, onde tais informações são armazenadas dentro de seus respectivos atributos globais "data-car" e "data-color".
Quando o usuário seleciona algum automóvel da lista, é direcionado a um formulário, que ao ser enviado, exibe uma mensagem dizendo qual foi o carro escolhido e sua cor. Até aqui, tudo bem!

O problema é que quando o usuário envia o formulário e retorna (através do botão Close) para escolher um novo automóvel na lista e envia um novo formulário, a informação exibida na tela é sempre a do primeiro automóvel escolhido.

O correto seria que quando fosse escolhido um novo modelo de automóvel, as informações do carro no formulário fossem sobrescritas e a informação na tela fosse a do novo carro escolhido, e não o primeiro.

Precisamos indicar uma solução e apontar o porquê isto está acontecendo.
Analisando o código, acreditamos que o problema seja resolvido alterando as primeiras linhas das 3 funções existentes em jQuery que se iniciam de maneiras diferentes:

**Função 1:** Escolhe o carro

```
$(function() {
```

**Função 2:** Fecha o formulário e retorna para a lista de carros

```
$(document).on('click', '.close', function(){
```

**Função 3:** Exibe a mensagem de carro qual carro foi o escolhido

```
$(document).ready(function () {
```

Quem puder nos ajudar e fazer com que esse sistema funcione de maneira correta, exibindo a mensagem adequadamente, será de nosso enorme prestígio e consideração.

Muito obrigada!

```js
$(function() {
  $(".cars").on('click', function() { //Função para escolher o carro
    var car = $(this).data('car'); //Escolhe o modelo do carro
    var color = $(this).data('color'); //Escolhe a cor do carro
    $('#carlist').addClass('d-none'); //Fecha a lista de carros
    $('#carinfo').removeClass('d-none'); //Abre o formulário
    $('#mycar').attr('data-car', car); //Altera o modelo do carro no formulário
    $('#mycar').attr('data-color', color); //Altera a cor do carro no formulário
  });
});

$(document).on('click', '.close', function() { //Função para fechar o formulário
  $('#carlist').removeClass('d-none'); //Aparece a lista de carros
  $('#carinfo').addClass('d-none'); //Some o formulário
  $('#mycar').attr('data-car', '0'); //Zera novamente o valor "car" do formulário
  $('#mycar').attr('data-color', '0'); //Zera novamente o valor "color" do formulário
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#form").on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); //Evita submeter o formulário via GET  
    var car = $('#mycar').data('car'); //Carrega o carro escolhido
    var color = $('#mycar').data('color'); //Carrega a cor escolhida
    alert(car + " - " + color); //Resultado

  });
});
```

```css
.cars {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.cars:hover {
  color: #FF0000;
}

.d-none {
  display: none;
}

.close {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.close:hover {
  color: #FF0000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

<div id="carlist">
  <div class="cars" data-car="BMW" data-color="black">BMW (Black)</div>
  <div class="cars" data-car="Audi" data-color="white">Audi (White)</div>
  <div class="cars" data-car="Ferrari" data-color="red">Ferrari (Red)</div>
  <div class="cars" data-car="Lamborghini" data-color="yellow">Lamborghini (Yellow)</div>
</div>

<div id="carinfo" class="d-none">
  <span class="close">Close</span>
  <form id="form">
    <input type="text" id="mycar" data-car="0" data-color="0" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Legal que esteja aprendendo, é normal quando estamos aprendendo algo fazermos algumas confusões, por exemplo:

> **1 -** Você não precisa declarar várias vezes dentro do mesmo escopo `$(document)`, pois no escopo da página apenas esta declaração `$(function()` que você fez já bastava.
>
> **2 -** Você misturou muito os métodos `attr` e `data`, causando acredito eu, uma pequena confusão para você na hora de manipular os dados.
>
> **3 -** Você não precisa zerar o formulário ou limpar nada, pois você já esta sempre pegando os dados atuais(escolhidos) com `$(this).data('car')` e `$(this).data('color')`

```js
$(function() {
  $(".cars").on('click', function() { //Função para escolher o carro
    var car = $(this).data('car'); //Escolhe o modelo do carro
    var color = $(this).data('color'); //Escolhe a cor do carro
    $('#carlist').addClass('d-none'); //Fecha a lista de carros
    $('#carinfo').removeClass('d-none'); //Abre o formulário
    $('#mycar').data('car', car); //Altera o modelo do carro no formulário
    $('#mycar').data('color', color); //Altera a cor do carro no formulário
    $('#mycar').val(car + " - " + color) // Insere os dados no input
  });


  $('.close').on('click', function() { //Função para fechar o formulário
    $('#carlist').removeClass('d-none'); //Aparece a lista de carros
    $('#carinfo').addClass('d-none'); //Some o formulário
  });


  $("#form").on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); //Evita submeter o formulário via GET  
    var car = $('#mycar').data('car'); //Carrega o carro escolhido
    var color = $('#mycar').data('color'); //Carrega a cor escolhida
    alert(car + " - " + color); //Resultado

  });
});
```

```css
.cars {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.cars:hover {
  color: #FF0000;
}

.d-none {
  display: none;
}

.close {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.close:hover {
  color: #FF0000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="carlist">
  <div class="cars" data-car="BMW" data-color="black">BMW (Black)</div>
  <div class="cars" data-car="Audi" data-color="white">Audi (White)</div>
  <div class="cars" data-car="Ferrari" data-color="red">Ferrari (Red)</div>
  <div class="cars" data-car="Lamborghini" data-color="yellow">Lamborghini (Yellow)</div>
</div>

<div id="carinfo" class="d-none">
  <button class="close">Close</button>
  <form id="form">
    <input type="text" id="mycar" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
  </form>
</div>
```